# Windows store app read / write text file

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm making a quiz game in windows metro. The problem I'm having is that the score doesn't remain after closing and re-opening the app.

I tried adding a text file into the package and then trying to write to it but that doesn't work.

I'm new to programming so I'd prefer not to get roasted if I've missed something obvious.

```
public async void CorrectAnswer()
    {


        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("SCORE.txt");
        Score++;
        var write = Score.ToString();

        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, write);
        this.score.Text = Score.ToString();
    }
```

Score is public static int;

thanks for your help

Comment: You can't write file just anywhere (even text file). What you're looking for is called isolated storage. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf96a1wz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Start reading here: [Store and retrieve settings and other app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299098.aspx). You would certainly want to use [ApplicationData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx).